# How can I select/update a row in the same transaction while locking the table from other consumers?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

I'm using an SQLite database with C# via Entity Framework.

I have a table named **Jobs**:

| Id | JobStatus | JobDetails |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | New | Some stuff to do |
| 2 | New | Some more stuff to do |
| 3 | New | Even more stuff |

I have multiple consumers of this table that will select the next row with a "New" status and process it.
I must ensure that the same job (row) cannot be picked up by a different consumer.
I know that SQLite supports table locking but not row locking.

I thought that the way to do this would be to start a transaction and inside select the next available row, then set its status to "InProgress".
I've written the following code which I think looks correct, but I'm not sure how to test it as this is a very narrow race condition:

```
public Job GetNextJob()
{
    Job job = null;

    using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            job = db.Jobs.Where(j => j.JobStatus == "New").FirstOrDefault();

            if (job != null )
            {
                job.JobStatus = "InProgress";
                db.SaveChanges();

                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }

    return job;
}
```

If multiple consumers called this method would it lock the Jobs table while this transaction completes, and thus prevent another consumer from selecting the same job? If not, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: IMHO add job status as a concurrency column https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations (or just a row timestamp...)

Comment: To ensure exclusive access to a job, set the transaction's isolation level to `Serializable`. This locks the table until the transaction ends.

```csharp
using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable))
{
    // Your code
}
```

This prevents multiple consumers from picking the same job but also blocks other table operations. Test thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at both of these suggestions.

Comment: SERIALIZABLE is generally not enough, as it still allows concurrent reads.  The solution will be engine-specific, and I don't know if SqlLite has anything.  In SQL Server you have to use the UPDLOCK hint on the query.  If this is a single process you can use .NET synchronization primitives like C# lock https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock, or ReaderWriterSlim. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=net-7.0